# spring migration from 3x to 4x to create hibernate session factory

Tags: spring, transactions, xa

I have a working project for spring XA transaction (http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077714/java-web-development/xa-transactions-using-spring.html). I modified the project downloaded and created pom.xml since i had to integrate it with my project. Initially i started with spring 3x. I got it working properly for spring 3x. Now i have to integrate it with hibernate, so in order to create hibernate session factory, i stated migrating it to spring 4x.

i have following entries in my config file for spring 3x

spring config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd ">

    <bean id="dsProps" class="java.util.Properties">
        <constructor-arg>
            <props>
                <prop key="user">root</prop>
                <prop key="password"></prop>
                <prop key="DYNAMIC_CLASS">com.findonnet.service.transaction.jboss.jdbc.Mysql
                </prop>
            </props>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource1"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.arjuna.ats.jdbc.TransactionalDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:arjuna:mysql://localhost:8888/mydb1" />
        <property name="connectionProperties">
            <ref bean="dsProps" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource2"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.arjuna.ats.jdbc.TransactionalDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:arjuna:mysql://localhost:8888/mydb2" />
        <property name="connectionProperties">
            <ref bean="dsProps" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- ===================================================== -->
    <!-- ==== TRANSACTION MANAGER CONFIG ===================== -->
    <!-- ===================================================== -->

    <bean id="jbossTransactionManager"
        class="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple">
    </bean>

    <bean id="jbossUserTransaction"
        class="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.UserTransactionImple" />

    <!-- use the JtaTransactionManager, since we have multiple resources to 
        deal with -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="jbossTransactionManager" />
        </property>
        <property name="userTransaction">
            <ref bean="jbossUserTransaction" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- Begin sequenceDAO bean. Handles persistence of seq num in the DB -->
    <bean id="sequenceDAO" class="com.findonnet.persistence.MessageSequenceDAO">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource1" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- End sequenceDAO bean -->

    <!-- Begin sequenceDAO2 bean. Handles persistence of seq num in the DB -->
    <bean id="sequenceDAO2" class="com.findonnet.persistence.MessageSequenceDAO">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource2" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- End sequenceDAO2 bean -->


    <bean id="eventHandlerTarget" class="com.findonnet.messaging.EventHandler">
    </bean>

    <!-- declarative transaction demarcation -->
    <bean id="eventHandler"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="transactionManager" />
        </property>
        <property name="target">
            <ref bean="eventHandlerTarget" />
        </property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="handle*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-RuntimeException</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>     
    </beans>
```

and the pom.xml is having following entry:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

This works completely fine. Now if i want to migrate to spring4x, i make the following changes:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd ">
```

and update my pom.xml as follows:

```
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

When i make the above changes and run my program, i get the following error:

```
    org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:628)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:907)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:968)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:973)
        at com.findonnet.persistence.MessageSequenceDAO.insertSequence(MessageSequenceDAO.java:22)
        at com.findonnet.messaging.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:53)
        at com.findonnet.messaging.EventHandler$$FastClassByCGLIB$$dd9a9fb0.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:713)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:646)
        at com.findonnet.messaging.EventHandler$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$14d5f3ff.handleEvent(<generated>)
        at com.findonnet.messaging.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:92)
```

Is there any other changes i have to make to get this project working with spring 4x.

I am trying to migrate to spring 4x since i have to make session factory as follows:

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryPayment"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcePayment" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:payment.hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Spring4 and Hibernate4. You do not need to change anything to your configuration to migrate your application to Spring 4. Your latest code snippet would be valid if you were trying to migrate your application to Hibernate4.

You can also omit the version altogher in your XML configuration as there is a mapping in the spring's jar that ensure that the latest available version is always used.

Comment: This is what i did: modified pom.xml to have 4.0.0.RELEASE spring details and kept the original spring cofig file same i.e. http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd. I am still getting the same error message

Comment: I can't see how the error message is related to the issue. This is basically saying it cannot connect to the JNDI tree to lookup your datasource.

Comment: I am getting this problem only if i change my pom.xml to use sprig 4x jars. If i use spring 3x jars, this problem does not exist.

Comment: attach relevant logs then please. Only changing the jars shouldn't do that, really.

Comment: I have put my code at https://www.dropbox.com/s/734k6l6seji3uk6/XA-Txn-mvn.rar . If you open the rar, the root folder contains MainApp.log. Also there is lib folder containing 3 jars which are required by application. The other jars can be downloaded by using pom.xml. Let me know if you need any other info from my side.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to solve the problem: I have my original program working for 3.0.7.RELEASE. I was trying to migrate to spring4 since i wanted to make use of org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean. Migrating to spring4 causing above exception by making use of 4.0.0.RELEASE.

Hibernate 4 support was added to Spring Framework in 3.1. So i replaced 3.0.7.RELEASE with 3.1.0.RELEASE and the problem (exception) is gone.